# Minification error with minifycss

Tags: css, gulp, minify, gulp-minify-css, gulp-clean-css

I've got this gulp css minification line:

```
.pipe(minifycss({advanced:false, keepSpecialComments : 0}).on('error', gutil.log))
```

When i minify this css part:

```
.mCS-rounded-dots.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail, 
.mCS-rounded-dots-dark.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail{
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAANElEQVQYV2NkIAAYiVbw//9/Y6DiM1ANJoyMjGdBbLgJQAX/kU0DKgDLkaQAvxW4HEvQFwCRcxIJK1XznAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: "alpha(opacity=30)"; 
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=30)";
}
```

i get this:

```
mCS-rounded-dots-dark.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail,.mCS-rounded-dots.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail{background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAANElEQVQYV2NkIAAYiVbw//9/Y6DiM1ANJoyMjGdBbLgJQAX/kU0DKgDLkaQAvxW4HEvQFwCRcxIJK1XznAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);background-repeat:repeat-y;opacity:.3;filter:"alpha(opacity=30)";-ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=30')"}
```

which breaks the whole css because of that bracket thing.

Are there any options i missed to avoid this? (can't switch to nanocss atm)

Comment: FYI gulp-minify-css has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note up front: if you landed here, you *might* be experiencing [issue #676](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/676), which means you need to upgrade your package.

---

You probably need to update your packages, or start some "bifurcation" debugging to find the actual root cause, because with the following setup your input will come out just fine. (In other words: status no repro for me.)

What I did to get your input to minify correctly, starting in a fresh repo:

```
npm install gulp -g
npm install gulp --save-dev
npm install gulp-minify-css --save-dev
npm install gulp-util --save-dev
```

This gave me this `package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.3",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7"
  }
}
```

I've fed this `styles.css` file (your code, as is):

```
.mCS-rounded-dots.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail, 
.mCS-rounded-dots-dark.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail{
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAANElEQVQYV2NkIAAYiVbw//9/Y6DiM1ANJoyMjGdBbLgJQAX/kU0DKgDLkaQAvxW4HEvQFwCRcxIJK1XznAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: "alpha(opacity=30)"; 
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=30)";
}
```

Into this `gulfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('default', [], function() {
    gulp.src('styles.css')
        .pipe(minifycss({advanced:false, keepSpecialComments : 0}).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
});
```

And then ran:

```
gulp
```

And got this output:

```
.mCS-rounded-dots-dark.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail,.mCS-rounded-dots.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail{background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAANElEQVQYV2NkIAAYiVbw//9/Y6DiM1ANJoyMjGdBbLgJQAX/kU0DKgDLkaQAvxW4HEvQFwCRcxIJK1XznAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);background-repeat:repeat-y;opacity:.3;filter:"alpha(opacity=30)";-ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=30)"}
```

As far as I can tell, this output is correct.

Which, when taken through the Stack Snippets "Tidy" feature, is equal to:

```css
.mCS-rounded-dots-dark.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail,
.mCS-rounded-dots.mCSB_scrollTools .mCSB_draggerRail {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAANElEQVQYV2NkIAAYiVbw//9/Y6DiM1ANJoyMjGdBbLgJQAX/kU0DKgDLkaQAvxW4HEvQFwCRcxIJK1XznAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  opacity: .3;
  filter: "alpha(opacity=30)";
  -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=30)"
}
```

Have you tried linting your input css? There may be a problem hidden in there somewhere...

---

PS. My output differs from yours as you have `url:('....`, that is a single quote there. I'd check your source for any stray quotes / nonmatching quotes.

Comment: Great answer. Yes i updated all my packages and probably it was an old minifycss package. after updating the error was gone. thanks!

Comment: @Mike Interesting. Your comment prompted me to browse through recently closed issues on the underlying "clean-css" tool, and I found [#676](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/676) which seems to be exactly your problem. - Glad your situation was fixed!

Comment: Just an FYI `gulp-minify-css` has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment to ask this, but do you mean it's breaking because of the brackets in the following:

```
filter: "alpha(opacity=30)"; 
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=30)";
```

If so, I would probably just drop these altogether. The opacity property on it's own is supported by all major browsers and since IE9 ([link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity)).

If you need IE 8 support, I suggest using autoprefixer and adding this to to your build tool after minification.

Comment: I did that at first, but then followed @Jeroen s advice.